# ForEach loop not pushing values to new array

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, mongoose

In my API while POST the route , i have to find the list of products which current user have in his Cart. I am having current user details then whenever i try to apply forEach loop on cart to extract information from my Products collection and pushing that info to new array and printing that new array, it is showing empty. while printing it inside forEach shows the data.
How do i fix it so it also prints the new array data?

```
  BuyerRoute.post("/Orders", verifyToken,async(req,res) =>{
    let buyer = await Buyer.findById(res.current_user.buyer_user._id)
    
    var e = []
    buyer.Buyer_Cart.forEach( async (prodObj) => {
        let products = await Products.findById(prodObj.Product_ID)
        e.push(products)
        
    })
    console.log(e)
   })
```

Output: []

While inside the forEach loop

```
    BuyerRoute.post("/Orders", verifyToken,async(req,res) =>{
    let buyer = await Buyer.findById(res.current_user.buyer_user._id)
    
    var e = []
    buyer.Buyer_Cart.forEach( async (prodObj) => {
        let products = await Products.findById(prodObj.Product_ID)
        e.push(products)
        console.log(e)
        
    })})
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    _id: new ObjectId("6381b9b4c5efd30fe8492902"),
    Product_name: 'headphones',
    Product_description: 'headphones for PC',
    Product_price: 500,
    Quantity_available: 10,
    seller_Id: '6381b7f3fdc04885a28723c1',
    seller_name: 'xyz',
    __v: 0
  }
]
```

Comment: In your first example `console.log(e)` gets called before the `e.push()` happens because you are awaiting something before that. To handle async code I'd recommend you use `Promise.all` (for example, depending on your needs) and `Array.prototype.map`.

Comment: You should do: `let e = await Promise.all(buyer.Buyer_Cart.map(prodObj => Products.findById(prodObj.Product_ID)))`

Comment: The post and forEach callbacks are asynchorize functions, so the output of your first code snippet does not wait until the results return, and got empty, however the second one can print inside the callback. Maybe you can make your forEach call async and so await the results.

Comment: Promise.all and map function works like a charm !!! thank you!!